# Next JS how to dynamically import images besides putting them in public folder?

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, markdown

I am making a textbook website where authors each contribute a textbook folder containing a markdown folder and an images folder:

```
textbooks
├───textbook-1
│   ├───images
│   └───markdown-files
└───textbook-2
    ├───images
    └───markdown-files
```

I am storing the textbooks folder in my project root folder and I am using 'fs' to read the files at build time. Until now I have had to place the images folders manually into the public folder, in order to use them in the markdown pages. Is there any way to import these image files dynamically without putting them into the public folder?

I am using ReactMarkdown to render the markdown and I was thinking about something along the lines of this:

```js
<NextImage src={import(`../../textbooks/textbook-1/images/${imgFile}`)} />
```

but it isn't working...

Answer (score 0):

One of the functional practices I have seen is to put all stored images in a centralized constant/*.ts

```js
import rectangle from "../assets/rectangle.svg";
import circle from "../assets/circle.svg";
import triangle from "../assets/triangle.svg";
import line from "../assets/line.svg";
import image from "../assets/image.svg";
import freeform from "../assets/freeform.svg";
import select from "../assets/select.svg";
import text from "../assets/text.svg";
import deleteIcon from "../assets/delete.svg";
import reset from "../assets/reset.svg";
import comments from "../assets/comments.svg";


export const shapeElements = [
  {
    icon: rectangle,
    name: "Rectangle",
    value: "rectangle",
  },
  {
    icon: circle,
    name: "Circle",
    value: "circle",
  },
  {
    icon: triangle,
    name: "Triangle",
    value: "triangle",
  },
  {
    icon: line,
    name: "Line",
    value: "line",
  },
  {
    icon: image,
    name: "Image",
    value: "image",
  },
  {
    icon: freeform,
    name: "Free Drawing",
    value: "freeform",
  },
];

export const navElements = [
  {
    icon: select,
    name: "Select",
    value: "select",
  },
  {
    icon: rectangle,
    name: "Rectangle",
    value: shapeElements,
  },
  {
    icon: text,
    value: "text",
    name: "Text",
  },
  {
    icon: deleteIcon,
    value: "delete",
    name: "Delete",
  },
  {
    icon: reset,
    value: "reset",
    name: "Reset",
  },
  {
    icon: comments,
    value: "comments",
    name: "Comments",
  },
];
```

Then use regular TS import to do the job.

```html
<Image
  src={shapeElements.find((el) => el.name === info?.name)?.icon}
  alt='Layer'
  width={16}
  height={16}
  className='group-hover:invert'
/>
```

It works if something like 'assets/image/xxx.svg' reports 404 because Next.js wants to load images from '_next/static'. Hope it helps

Answer (score -4):

You need to import the image such as you do with other modules using the `Image` component from `next/image`. Below is an example from nextjs docs [next/image](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image)

```
import Image from 'next/image'
import profilePic from '../public/me.png'

function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>My Homepage</h1>
      <Image src={profilePic} alt="Picture of the author" />
      <p>Welcome to my homepage!</p>
    </>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Comment: yes but in the example the image is stored in the public folder. I want to know if it's possible to store the image in a different folder... also how could I make the import a dynamic one?

Comment: Use `require` instead of import.

Comment: My best second guess would be to create a separate route `/api/images` component that serves those images but you'll lack image optimization, unless you'll optimize them yourself at build.

Comment: I tried using `require` but now I am running into another weird behavior. If I use `require(\`../../textbooks/textbook-1/images/${imgFile}\`)` this works perfectly. However I introduce another dynamic segment such as `require(\`../../textbooks/${textbookName}/images/${imgFile}\`)` this breaks the code and I get an error that the module cannot be found. Is this a webpack config issue perhaps?

Comment: This doesnt answer the question about dynamic import.